# How can i trigger a timer-stopped event in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i have a timer in angularjs defined as follow:

```
<timer interval="1000"  countdown="offerta.dataScadenza/1000 - currentTimestamp" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope ng-binding">{{days}} days, {{hours}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds</timer>
```

it works correctly but i want to trigger an event when the countdown reaches his end doing some busness logic when that event occurs.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [timer tag has a few events](http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/index.html) that you can listen to, including `timer-stopped`

```
    $scope.$on('timer-stopped', function (event, data){
        console.log('Timer Stopped - data = ', data);
    });
```

It also has methods you can call, even from JS

```
    function startTimer() {
        document.getElementsByTagName('timer')[0].start();
    }

    function stopTimer() {
        document.getElementsByTagName('timer')[0].stop();
    }
```

Comment: and where i invoke those method? i want they are invoked automatically when the end of the countdown occurs.

Comment: i tried also this but doen't work even with a simple countdown from 100 seconds to 0

Comment: @josè Don't just say I tried, please show the code you used (in your question) and say what happened, error message, even if it's just my handler wasn't called Their example at http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/examples.html shows that it does work in that case at least, you need to figure out what's different in your case

Comment: i put your $scope.$on code on my controller that is associated with the template in which is contained the countdown, the console doesn't show any errors but doesn't dysplay any log.

Comment: it works with the 'timer-tick' event, does not recognize the 'event-stop' event..

Comment: `event-stop`? or `timer-stopped`?

Comment: timer-stopped sorry, it doesn't work with timer-stopped event